# python server when i close 5 clients the server not work more

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, server, mysql-python

when I close 4 clients all work, but when I close 5 clients all disconnects from the server, but when I open the game again the server get message, but not send,
this code called when I close client

```
def close_client(index):
   index = int(index)
   while int(index) >= len(all_clients) and all_clients.__len__() > 0:
    print("index go down")
    index -= 1
all_client_index = 0
for c in all_clients:
    if all_client_index == int(index):
        name = c['name']
        if name != "":
            close_player(name)
    all_client_index += 1

while int(index) >= len(all_clients) and all_clients.__len__() > 0:
    print("index go down")
    index -= 1
all_clients.pop(index)
print("online player : {0}".format(all_clients.__len__()))

new_index = 0
for i in all_clients:
    try:
        i['client'].sendall("you index is/{0}*".format(new_index).encode())
    except:
        continue
    new_index += 1

# send to all client that the player close
if name != "":
    for i in all_clients:
        if i['name'] != "":
            try:
                name = RemoveSpace(name)
                LeaveChat(name,  i['client'])
                # i['client'].sendall("{0} leave the 
                chat/{0}/{1}*".format(name, 5).encode())
            except:
                continue
```

This is the code that connects to the database

```
def connect_db():
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="game_db",
    buffered=True,
    autocommit=True
)
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide and then provide a sufficient code snippet. Please avoid posting images of codes instead of putting the code here.

Comment: @nima send the code here? and if is long code?

Comment: Yes, It is much more readable and usable if you put it here. As I can see in the attached images, your code does not seem that long. And even your code has many lines, you should be able to provide a minimal reproducible snippet.

Comment: @nima ok i do that